# Polymer element doesn't trigger the "on-<property>-changed" event when property changes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer, dom-events, polymer-1.0

I am using the [google-sigin](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-signin) element from the [Polymer catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org). I want to listen to changes for the `signedIn` attribute outside the polymer element. The property is set to `notify: true` and in the [Polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#change-notification-protocol) related to change notifications, it says that:

> When using a Polymer element with other elements or frameworks, you can manually attach an on-property-changed listener to an element to be notified of property changes, and take the necessary actions based on the new value.

I have tried listening to `on-signIn-changed`, `on-sign-in-changed`, `on-property-changed`, `signIn-changed` and `sign-in-changed`, but none of these events are being triggered.

The code that listens to the event looks like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.querySelector('google-signin').addEventListener('on-signIn-changed', function() {
        // never gets called
    });
});
```

I know that I could be listening to the `google-signin-success` event (which works  and I can see that `signedIn` has been changed to `true`), but I want to understand why the event isn't being triggered/what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try `addEventListener('signIn-changed'` without the `on-`?

Comment: @JustinXL I did indeed. As mentioned in my question, I tried `on-signIn-changed`, `on-sign-in-changed`, `on-property-changed`, `signIn-changed` and `sign-in-changed`.

Comment: Oops sorry I must be blind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that property is called `signedIn` not `signIn`. Have you tried `addEventListener('signed-in-changed'`?

Comment: You are right, all this time I was using the wrong attribute name. `signedIn-changed` didn't work, but fortunately I tried all the combinations I had previously tried and it turns out that `signed-in-changed` is the event that is being triggered. Good thing to know. Thank you for taking the time to answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the correct name of the event. I have updated the answer, in case anyone is looking for it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to notify an external script to a Polymer element property change:

- Make sure that `notify` is set to `true` on the property definition.
- From the external script, attach an event listener on the element.
  The event name should be `property-name-changed`, where `property-name`
  is the dash-case version of the property name (`this.firstName` fires
  `first-name-changed`).
- Assuming that the event listener's argument name is `e`, access
  the new property value at `e.detail.value`.

Example:

```
<body>
  <!-- assume x-el changes its number property somehow -->
  <x-el number="1></x-el>
  <script>
    (function(document) {
      var el = document.querySelector('x-el');
      el.addEventListener('number-changed', function(e) {
        console.log('the new value is ' + e.detail.value);
      });
    })(document);
  </script>
</body>
```

I'm adding a section to the docs now, it will be documented at --> https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#notify-external

Here's a jsbin for tinkering --> http://jsbin.com/risevu/edit?html,output